# How do i make this code search across the work sheet, right now it only searches row A

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String

    On Error GoTo Err

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set oRange = ws.Columns(1)

    SearchString = "2"

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        FoundAt = aCell.Address
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
    End If

    MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `row A` in Excel. It's column A you're talking about.

Comment: Can't spot any c++ relevance removed the tag.

Comment: Your `oRange` is defined as `ws.Columns(1)` which is why it is only searching in column A.  If you want it to search the whole sheet, change it to be `ws.UsedRange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")


    On Error GoTo Err


    Set oRange = ws.Cells

    SearchString = "2"

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        FoundAt = aCell.Address
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
    End If

    MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description


End Sub
```

Comment: I get an invalid reference cells(.Cols.Count)

Comment: Try again I just made the change suggested by @Siva

Comment: One more thing, i just noticed it only searches for the exact word, but if its in a sentence it doesn't recognize it, you have any ideas?

Comment: @AyodeleAwe Change this `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `lookat:=xlpart`

Answer (score 2):

Your range is referring to Column A , set range to All Cells in the sheet

```
  Set oRange = ws.Cells
```